# Hatcher 1.1.18 - sufficient solution?

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

Could someone check the following solution to Hatcher 1.1.18? I'm wondering whether the arguments in the end using van Kampen are sufficient in normal proof-writing in algebraic topology.

Problem:

[image]

[image]

Proof: Assume $\alpha \in \pi_1 \left( X \right) $.
Let $\varphi  \colon S^{1} \to X$ be the attaching map.
We can let $p  \colon I \to S^{1}$ by $t \to \left( \cos 2\pi t, \sin
2 \pi t\right) $. Then $\varphi \circ p$ is the attaching loop.

Let $x_0 = \left( \varphi \circ p \right) (0) \in A$.
Now, since $A$ is path-connected, there exists
a path $\gamma  \colon I \to A$ from $\alpha (0)$ to $x_0$.

Then $\gamma \alpha \overline{\gamma}$ is a loop
at $x_0$ in $A$.

Now choose a neighborhood around $x_0$ and let
$A_1$ be the union of this neighborhood and the attached
$n$-cell. Let $A_2$ be an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of
$A$ in $X$ that deformation retracts onto $A$ - this
becomes $A$ union an annulus of the attached $n$-cell.
And the annulus deformation retracts onto the attaching
circle of $A$.

The intersection of $A_1$ and $A_2$ is path-connected - the union of the annulus with the neighborhood around $x_0$ -, so
by lemma 1.15, the loop can be decomposed into running
in $A_1$ and $A_2$. Any loop in $A_1$ however is
nullhomotopic in $X$, so it can be decomposed into loops
running in $A_2$ only. Now deformation retract $A_2$ to
$A$ and we find the loop  $\alpha$ can be decomposed
into loops running in $A$ only.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've made a few typos/mistakes in the beginning. For example, the attaching map is a map $\varphi:S^n\to A$, where $n\geq 1$, not a map into $X$. Also, $\gamma\alpha\overline{\gamma}$ isn't a loop in $A$ (you chose $\alpha$ to be a loop in $X$... what if $\alpha$ is a loop completely contained in $\varphi(e^n)$).

However, in the rest of the argument I think you sort of have the right idea. I'm a bit confused on what you mean by the annulus bit. Also, it isn't clear where you're picking the basepoint $x_0$ for $\pi_1(X,x_0)$. If I were to write the solution I'd go as follows.

Choose a basepoint $x_0$ in $\varphi(S^n)$ and let $\alpha$ be a loop in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$. We have that $X$ is the union of spaces $\varphi(e^n)$ and $A$ - both of which are path-connected. We can choose open neighborhoods of $\varphi(e^n)$ and $A$ in $X$, both of which deformation retract onto the respective subspaces, whose intersection deformation retracts onto $\varphi(S^n)$. Now, by the lemma,  $\alpha$ is homotopic to a product of loops $\beta\gamma$, where $\beta$ is a loop in $\varphi(e^n)$ and $\gamma$ is a loop in $A$ (technically loops in the open neighborhoods that deformation retract, but it's okay to ignore that point precisely because these neighborhoods deformation retract). We have that $\varphi(e^n)$ is simply-connected for $n\geq 2$, hence $\beta$ is null-homotopic and it follows $\alpha$ is homotopic to $\gamma$. We see $\gamma$ is the desired loop satisfying $i_*[\gamma]=[\alpha]$, where $i:A\to X$ is the inclusion.